# Disable outlook 2003 toast notification programmatically?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2003

Hopefullay an easy answer but is it possible to disable outlook 2003 toast pop-up notification programmatically?

Note: I'm working in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Frank White for giving me the initial clue :)

Heres the complete answer to my question.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

//this will create the subkey or if it already exists will just get the location. there is //no getsubkey in the registryclass

RegistryKey rkRegOutlookPreferences = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook\Preferences");

//this will add in or change a value in that subkey

rkRegOutlookPreferences.SetValue("NewmailDesktopAlerts", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);

//there is also getValue; this will return a null if the value doesnt exist

rkRegOutlookPreferences.GetValue("NewmailDesktopAlerts")

//and deleting 

rkRegOutlookPreferences.DeleteValue("NewmailDesktopAlerts");
```

There is more but this completes the full answer to my question. And thanks again to Frank White for giving me the first steps.

Answer (score 1):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version number here>\Outlook\Preferences\NewmailDesktopAlerts
```

Change that to a zero.